# Nodejs encrypt and decrypt video file using crypto-js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs

I need to encrypt and decrypt video file using crypto-js. I have follwing code as shown below. The code generate encrypted and decrypted file, but the decrypted file not able play. I also seen that the decrypted file size larger compared to the original source.

What cold be the problem?

```
const FormData = require('form-data');
var fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

function aes_encrypt(str_to_encrypt){

  var key = "sgftyrfacert6hjaddd4rl"; //length=22
  var iv  = "fgry5shghdy5ghy6sgh55h"; //length=22
  key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key);
  iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(iv);


  //var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(str_to_encrypt, key, { iv: iv });
  var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(str_to_encrypt,key, { iv: iv });
  var encryptedString = encrypted.toString();
  return  encryptedString;
}

function aes_decrypt(str_to_decrypt){
  var key = "sgftyrfacert6hjaddd4rl"; //length=22
  var iv  = "fgry5shghdy5ghy6sgh55h"; //length=22
  key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key);
  iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(iv);
  //var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(str_to_decrypt,  key, { iv: iv });
  var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(str_to_decrypt,key, { iv: iv });
  var decryptedString = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
  return decryptedString;
}

function streamToString (stream) {
  const chunks = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    stream.on('data', (chunk) => chunks.push(Buffer.from(chunk)));
    stream.on('error', (err) => reject(err));
    stream.on('end', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf8')));
  })
}


async function encrypt(){

  var file="video.mp4";
  
   var infile = fs.createReadStream(file);
   const result = await streamToString(infile);
   var outfile = fs.createWriteStream(file+".enc");
   var encrypted = aes_encrypt(result);
   outfile.write(encrypted);
   outfile.close();


    var infile1 = fs.createReadStream(file+".enc");
    const result1 = await streamToString(infile1);
    var decrypted = aes_decrypt(result1);
    var outfile1 = fs.createWriteStream(file+".dec");
    outfile1.write(decrypted);
    outfile1.close();

}

encrypt();
```

Comment: Why are you using `crypto-js` when Node.js already has a built-in `crypto` module?

Comment: I have to use it because I am using the same library for my client side javascript in web-browser.

Comment: Crypto implementations are generally inter-operable: you should be able to use any two implementations together. In any case, you're using crypto-js with strings, which are unsuitable for keeping binary data. You should be using Buffers instead, and not treat video files as `utf-8`.

Comment: As you said I think the the problem with utf-8 conversion in vidoe file, if I use text file the above code works fine.